# Linq query to select the records based on the given months for a year

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing linq query and finding it difficult to construct the logic using linq syntax. Basically I need to extract records that match the indexid and filter records based on months in the months array and year field. How do I check months array in the linq query

Here is what I am trying but not sure how to check for x.PriceDate.Month against months array

```
 private Tuple<double?, double?> GetBenchMarkByYear(int year, int benchMark1,  int[] months)
        {
            Tuple<double?, double?> benchMarkReturns;
            double[] temp1 = null;

            var benchMark1Returns = new double?[] { };

           benchMark1Returns = GetViewService<MV_INDEX_PERFORMANCE>()
             .Where(x => x.Mtd != null && x.IndexId == benchMark1 && x.PriceDate.Year == year && x.PriceDate.Month ).Select(x => x.Mtd)
             .ToArray();
        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like `months.Contains(x.PriceDate.Month)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `Any()` method.

Which mean your condition will be as following:

```
benchMark1Returns = GetViewService<MV_INDEX_PERFORMANCE>()
  .Where(x => x.Mtd != null && x.IndexId == benchMark1 && x.PriceDate.Year == year && months.Any(m=> m == x.PriceDate.Month))
  .Select(x => x.Mtd)
  .ToArray();
```

That if of course the entity **x.PriceDate.Month** is of type ***int*** since months if an array of integers.